# State of Decay cannot relocate homebase to trucking warehouse

Tags: state-of-decay, state-of-decay-breakdown, state-of-decay-yose

Guys this is driving me nuts!

I have 50 material, 14 survivors and I can't move my home to Snyder Trucking Warehouse.
When I try, Lily just keeps saying, "does it have a wall around it? Like a, defensible perimeter?" 
And my character keeps answering no. 
How do you sort this out?

Comment: You've used tags for multiple DLC packs - are they actually relevant here?

Comment: @Ash Already removed 1 tag because it's obviously not the Lifeline DLC, as for the State of Decay and State of Decay YOSE tag, he is playing one of the versions. Probably the later as that one includes all the DLCs

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what game mode are you playing? Story or Breakdown?

For the story, you must have progressed far enough to be able to move bases.
If you are playing Breakdown, I suggest you make sure you have cleared the area before trying to relocate. To many zeds in the area can prevent certain actions.

Also, make sure you have enough Influence to order a move.

Comment: Sorry... To clarify, I'm playing story mode. And I've done the mission where you look at the house as relocation possibility.